# Django - Automatically Assign Cleaned Data to Database Fields

Tags: python, django

The usual way I do form handling is like this:

```
contact = Contact(
                name=form.cleaned_data['name'],
                email=form.cleaned_data['email'],
                message=form.cleaned_data['message'],
                newsletter=form.cleaned_data['newsletter']
            )
```

but for long forms, this obviously is a tedious task. I was wondering if there was any Django method I might have missed that automatically assigns the cleaned data to their corresponding column in the database table that I don't have to manually assign them.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django offers you a [Modelform class](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/modelforms/) that was desgined for exactly this task.